# What kind of world would it be when its main species are slimes?

Tags: mythical-creatures

So the kind of slimes I'm thinking of are those with a nucleus or crystal core of sorts that acts as the slime's brains. Their body would be made of something like nerve cells that stick to each other in an elaborate mesh. This allows the core to control their body. They would be able to eat most stuff but the slimes would evolve to suit what they eat [say, if they were eating plenty of bones, they would evolve to be more corrosive, thus allowing them to eat/dissolve the bones faster becoming an Acid slime].

The slimes are not capable of communication [they don't know what that is] thus it's a slime eat slime world where bigger nasty slimes devour their smaller cousins [and whatever in their way - they make great lawn mowers]. However their size won't grow forever, they will stop at a certain limit depending on their evolution [can't have them bigger than the world]. When they reach their limit, they become capable of splitting into two.

**But what kind of animals and plants would have evolved among these conditions and in general what kind of world would it be like?**  Assuming that the world composition is something like earth with the core, mantle and crust, oceans and whatnot.

I'm looking for what might be able to **predate** on the slimes and what **adaptations the plants can have to counter the slimes**

Comment: Considering the extreme variety of life on Earth alone, especially when looking offer the billions of years life has existed here, it would be completely impossible to say what it would be like on your fictional world with the very little "constraints" you have put on it. You can make up pretty much anything you want. :)

Comment: Rather than slime being one species, it would more like a genre, with lots of sub species. One of precursor to benefit evolution of slime, would be probably high pressure, as unique individual systems would be hard to form, you can start from here, and predict how plants and animal would be in high grav, high pressure atmosphere. Plants would probably smaller, algae like. Insects would more common, bigger mammals would be rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ever changing types of poisons would be employed by plants for protection. So that when a slime type manages to evolve an immunity to that poison, that plant would be producing another type of poison. Flight would be more common as it would be easier for flying animals to survive. The path leading to slime would not be much different from the slime on earth. Just one day slime manages to capture neuron cells of an organism and manages symbiotic relationship to it. [Siphonophorae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphonophorae) is a similar type of symbiotic colony.

Answer (score 3):

In this world there could be a whole host of insects that predatorize these slimes. Imagine a mosquito sized insect that lands gently on the surface of a slime. Maybe the mosquito is so light the slime does not notice. or maybe this particular slime evolved to mainly feed on plants or significantly larger animals. In either case the insect lays its eggs in the slime. This might be a simple way to protect its offspring till they are ready to fly away. Or the slime maybe a source of food for the larva. Just as a tapeworm on this planet begins its life after entering the host digestive track this insect begins its life inside the slime.

There may be snail/clam creatures with hard shells that prove to be resistant to the slimes digestive enzymes. Whenever a slime comes around they just retreat into their shells and pretended to be an indigestible rock till the slimes passes.

If these slime prove to be environmentally devastating (they eat everything), then other forms of life might prosper in places that the slimes cannot reach.
Are the slimes aquatic? Maybe sea life is the second dominant life form.
Can the slimes survive below zero temperatures? Maybe penguins and polar bear like critters live long prosperous live free of the slime nightmares.

Answer (score 0):

The world would have to look more like a giant cell were the slimes can move in all directions. If the slime world had slimes just living on the crust, then It would be easy for the slimes just to dry out from wind, heat, and etc. If anything, the planet would look like a giant ocean. as far as a environment, Can't really see much **because they consume all!** Maybe that is goal of your slime creatures... to consume all and become so big that they actually become a planet or consume planets!